# Restore a MSSQL Database (No file ext)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database backup named "database". I have a backup from MSSQL Server 2012. But the type of file is not ".bak". I switched to the new server. But I could not restore the backup of the database.

When I look at the file content with "10Editor" I can see the records in the database.

The size of the file is also quite large (about 3 GB).

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to restore from SQL2012 to SQL2008? That won't work. The name of the file doesn't matter at all though. What error message are you getting?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "upload"? As long as the backup is from the same or earlier SQL version, you can use `RESTORE DATABASE`.

Comment: I do not remember the previous SQL version. But I know it's 2012. The version is also 2012. I did not know how to restore the file anyway.

Comment: When I do a restore, it only accepts the .BAK file. If I open it as a file, there are no databases that appear.

Comment: This is error image ; https://ibb.co/ivSPkS

Comment: @user3186216, you could simply rename by file to a 'bak` extension or just use a `RESTORE DATABASE` T-SQL command.

Comment: The problem continues. I tried all versions of MSSQL, but it still did not get resolved.

Comment: I try the check version of backup in MSSQL 2012. But no info : https://ibb.co/ikc4Kn

Comment: Your "backup" is corrupt (or possibly not even an actual backup file); it is not usable. Start over by creating a new, valid backup file.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: My backup file was corrupted. I backup from start, and no problem for now.